# What's a positive phrase to say that I quoted something not word by word

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, quotations

Sometimes I quote in my writing sombody else, but I do not know the exact words the other person had used. What is a concise and *positive*(*) phrase to describe this? I found different options on the net:

- *I quote **keeping with the sense**: "..."*
- *I quote **in spirit**: "..."*
- *I quote **conceptually**: "..."*

or even:

- *I **paraphrase**:  "..."*

However I am not sure what's the normal/standard way to phrase this.

---

(*) With positive I mean I want to avoid a phrase like *I quote **not** to the letter*  or *I quote **not** word for word*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Succinct word or phrase to begin quoting approximately what someone said](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367592/succinct-word-or-phrase-to-begin-quoting-approximately-what-someone-said) Or this? [What is a 'nearly-quotation' called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197161/what-is-a-nearly-quotation-called/197162#197162) Both offer **paraphrase**.

Comment: If it's not a quote, it's not a quote, it's "like ___ says" vs "as __ says".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good find!

Comment: @dandavis Mmmh, I think there is a notion of _quoting_ somebody (i.e. more than just expressing the  general gist of somebody's statement), even if it is not to the letter...

Comment: If it's a good find, your question has already been answered on ELU; deleting it will reduce bloatware.

Comment: Perhaps "in my own words" could work?

Comment: @Vilx- That's a good one. Worth an answer IMHO.

Comment: OK, added an answer. :)

Comment: Still not deleted.

Comment: I *quote from memory...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion:

> I quote in my own words.

This doesn't have either a positive or a negative connotation, just that you don't remember it precisely and will attempt to reconstruct it as best you can from memory.

Comment: I reckon that’s exactly what I was after: "I quote in my own words:...” So it is still the act of quoting just not to the dot of the i.

Comment: I feel the edit did more harm than good. The edit added the OP's solution above "I quote…" but the original answer was "in my own words" and I find this turn of phrase far more natural and acceptable. If you are quoting someone, that's what you do, you *repeat* their exact words you don't change the line.

Answer (score 57):

**Paraphrase** is the perfect word.

> *To paraphrase Churchill, we will fight them everywhere.*

Or

> *Paraphrasing Churchill, we will fight them everywhere.*

There are plenty of examples at [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/paraphrase).

Or, less formally, you could use **[gist](https://www.lexico.com/definition/gist)**:

> *He said, "We will fight them everywhere." That, at least, was his
> gist.*

Or

> *He said, "We'll fight them all over the place," or words to that effect.*

Comment: Thanks! What about _Quoting in spirit_? Is that misleading?

Comment: In reagrds to the word _pharaphrase_: If I want to stick to the verb '_quote_', could I say _I quote Churchill by paraphrasing: "We will fight..."_?

Comment: We don't say *quoting in spirit*. No, you can't mix "quote" and "paraphrase": it's one or the other. If you quote someone you need to do it accurately. If it's not verbatim then you can't use *quote* or *quoting*. What have you got against *paraphrase*?

Comment: You can say “loosely quoted.”

Comment: I have nothing against _paraphrase_. :-) The _I quote_ probably sticks in my head, because in German we say "Ich zitiere" even if we modify it with something like "_loosely/true to the sense/words to that effect_"...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Xanne and OldBrixtonian. Makes all sense.

Comment: @halloleo: You're welcome! (What have you got against *All makes sense*?  :-)

Comment: While it's certainly true in general that "quoting" is assumed to be verbatim unless specified not to be, one context in which that doesn't apply is exemplified by henning's answer - when the original was in a different language.

Comment: The example that is offered to illustrate *gist* seems problematic. Its second sentence is at odds with the first one: if that is merely the gist of what he said, then he did not actually say it. Also, *gist* is unlike *paraphrase*, in that it implies that only the core of what somebody said is being conveyed, that the less important details have been omitted.

Comment: Perhaps it should be incorporated into the answer that paraphrasing and quoting are mutually exclusive concepts. The OP asked what is the word for quoting something, but not word for word. Although *paraphase* is, obviously, the word that the OP needs, the answer to the question **as formulated** is that there is no such word, because there is no such thing as quoting that is not word for word.

Answer (score 12):

Paraphrase is perfectly good here, and probably the most natural choice in most written contexts e.g.

> *Paraphrasing Oscar Wilde, "truth isn't pure or simple"*

You could also caveat the word "quote" with suitable hedges. The suggestions in the question ("keeping with the sense", "in spirit", and "conceptually") don't feel right to me though, and seem somewhat of an oxymoron together with the word "quote". I would expect something like "loosely" or "roughly" e.g.

> *Loosely quoting Oscar Wilde, "truth isn't pure or simple"*

Indirect speech is also generally assumed to be paraphrased, and often summarised e.g.

> *Oscar Wilde said that truth wasn't pure or simple*

In especially informal contexts, quotative "like" indicates that speech is paraphrased, often with subtext drawn to the surface, and often for dramatic or humorous effect especially with a slightly exaggerated tone e.g.

> *Oscar Wilde was like, "that's rubbish, **truth** isn't pure **or** simple!"*

There are also lots of phrases that can be used with direct speech to show that it's been paraphrased, but these generally only work with the verb "to say", and not "to quote" (which has the strong implication that the words that follow are verbatim). They can also often occur both immediately before or after the quote often with slight changes in the wording of the hedge e.g.

> *Oscar Wilde said, "truth isn't pure or simple", or words to that effect*

> *Oscar Wilde said words to the effect of, "truth isn't pure or simple"*

Comment: (For more on Churchill's relationship with Oscar Wilde go [here](https://historynewsnetwork.org/article/156185).)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, "to paraphrase" is perfectly apt. An alternative with a slightly broader [meaning](https://www.lexico.com/definition/borrow) is "to borrow", as in:

> Borrowing from [Seneca](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/17490-luck-is-what-happens-when-preparation-meets-opportunity), luck is a function of preparation and
> opportunity.

Comment: This seems to me _too_ broad to be considered as a phrase for quoting approximately.

Answer (score 1):

As spotted in Tristan's answer, "summarise" could also be used in some contexts.

> Indirect speech is ...  often **summarised** e.g. ...

Answer (score 1):

I've'd [sic] to face this in a book I am writing, chronicling our community (Uganda Asians/Indians)'s history. I have to bring in materials from written texts. If it's a quote it's a quote and quote marks have to be used. But I also have to summarize/paraphrase often in which case I say at the start of an extraction: >>In their own words but often extrapolated, except when an exact quotation is used in which case I use quote marks.<< "Exact quote" itself is a difficult thing to adhere to. Often you add something in which case square brackets are used and omit something in which case ellipses are used.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use "If I recall correctly" which is frequently abbreviated to IIRC so examples might be:

- If I recall correctly Fred said "Yabba Dabba Who"
- Fred said "Yabba Dabba Who" (IIRC)

The other common phrase is "Words to the effect of..." e.g.: Maggie said words to the effect of "they can make an effort to find work".